# Is it possible to mix-in from mixin function parameter?

Tags: less

Basically, I want to be able to loop through break points creating, say centre-block-* classes.

Code:

```
.centre-block {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@breakpoints: xs 479px, sm 767px, md 991px, lg 1200px;

.make-classes(centre-block, @breakpoints);

.make-classes(@prefix, @list) {
    .iter(length(@list));

    .iter(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        .iter(@i - 1);

        @pair:  extract(@list, @i);
        @key:   extract(@pair, 1);
        @value: extract(@pair, 2);

        @media (max-width: @value) {
            .@{prefix}-@{key} {
                .@{prefix};
            }
        }

    }
}
```

From that, what I want to be able to do is add a class, say `centre-block-sm` that, when the screen size is under 768px the `.centre` classes `margin: 0 auto` will be applied. But I want to be able to do this for numerous class types, like adding a `no-padding-*` class list.

Everything works except for the fact it will not use the `.@{prefix}`, and instead simply doesn't recognise it. If I replace `.@{prefix}` with `.centre-block` it works. Is there a way around this, perhaps a different approach to the problem?

I feel like this sort of functionality is what LESS was designed for, so I might just be missing the point altogether.

Comment: Change your `.centre-block` class selector into a detached ruleset and pass it to the mixin. You can pass a different ruleset everytime you make a mixin call and so it is not static (like manually calling `.centre-block` within the `.@{prefix}-@{key}` selector). I can post a sample as answer if you wish to go down that route. What you're currently trying is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Would you mind sending an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is currently not possible with Less. You can find this discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/617). Though there is not much explanation in this, you can see that other linked thread within this (#1133) which mentions that this functionality is not yet implemented.

You could have a look at using [detached rulesets](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) as an alternative. In your code, convert the top level class selector (`.centre-block`) into a detached ruleset, store it as a variable and then pass it as one parameter to the mixin. We can then invoke this ruleset within the mixin call and it will print the content of the ruleset as it is into whichever selector we need. Below is a sample:

```
@centre-block : {margin: 0 auto;}; /* a detached ruleset */

@breakpoints: xs 479px, sm 767px, md 991px, lg 1200px;

.make-classes(centre-block, @breakpoints, @centre-block); /* pass the extra param */

.make-classes(@prefix, @list, @ruleset) { /* add the extra param */
    .iter(length(@list));

    .iter(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        .iter(@i - 1);

        @pair:  extract(@list, @i);
        @key:   extract(@pair, 1);
        @value: extract(@pair, 2);

        @media (max-width: @value) {
            .@{prefix}-@{key} {
                @ruleset(); /* invoke the ruleset */
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.